# Pandas - make a large DataFrame into several small DataFrames and run each through a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset with about 60000 data. I would first use some criteria to do groupby on the whole dataset, and what I want to do next is to separate the whole dataset to many small datasets within the criteria and to run a function to each of the small dataset automatically to get a parameter for each small dataset. I have no idea on how to do this. Is there any code to make it possible?
This is what I have

```
Date         name    number
20100101    John      1
20100102    Kate      3
20100102    Kate      2
20100103    John      3
20100104    John      1
```

And I want it to be split into two small ones

```
Date         name    number
20100101    John      1
20100103    John      3
20100104    John      1

Date         name    number
20100102    Kate      3
20100102    Kate      2
```

Comment: Why can you not just loop through chunks of your DataFrame?

Comment: @benten Does loop only work from row to row? Then how can I split the DataFrame into many small ones?

Answer (score 3):

I think a more efficient way than filtering the original data set using subsetting is `groupby()`, as a demo:

```
for _, g in df.groupby('name'):
    print(g)

#       Date  name  number
#0  20100101  John       1
#3  20100103  John       3
#4  20100104  John       1
#       Date  name  number
#1  20100102  Kate       3
#2  20100102  Kate       2
```

So to get a list of small data frames, you can do `[g for _, g in df.groupby('name')]`.

To expand on this answer, we can see more clearly what `df.groupby()` returns as follows:

```
for k, g in df.groupby('name'):
    print(k)
    print(g)

# John
#        Date  name  number
# 0  20100101  John       1
# 3  20100103  John       3
# 4  20100104  John       1
# Kate
#        Date  name  number
# 1  20100102  Kate       3
# 2  20100102  Kate       2
```

For each element returned by `groupby()`, it contains a key and a data frame with `name` which has a unique value of the key. In the above solution, we don't need the key, so we can just specify a position holder and discard it.

Comment: when I tried this one, it returned me a SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Do you know why this happened?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what you have tried, especially with a such one liner.

Comment: So I am not sure what is '_' and 'g' here. Could you explain it more? Thanks.

Comment: `df.groupby('name')` returns a list of tuples where the first element is the key, in this case, would be `John and Kate` and the second element is the data frame with unique keys `_` is just a position holder because we don't need the key, and `g` is the small data frames. you can also specify as `k,g` which is the same thing except that `k` is not used in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your function is really slow, this can probably be accomplished by slicing (e.g. `df_small = df[a:b]` for some indices a and b). The only trick is to choose a and b. I use `range` in the code below but you could do it other ways:

```
param_list = []
n = 10000 #size of smaller dataframe

# loop up to 60000-n, n at a time
for i in range(0,60000-n,n):
    # take a slice of big dataframe and apply function to get 'param'
    df_small = df[i:i+n] #
    param = function( df_small )

    # keep our results in a list
    param_list.append(param)
```

EDIT: Based on update, you could do something like this:

```
# loop through names
for i in df.name.values.unique():
    # take a slice of big dataframe and apply function to get 'param'
    df_small = df[df.name==i]
```

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear before. My df is one with many different person. I want to split the df into small ones with each one collects all data from the df of the same person. I have edited the post to describe it more clearly. Is it still possible though? Thanks.

Comment: docs for selecting rows from pandas dataframes: [http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html]

Comment: Thanks I'll check the document later. But when I tried this one, it returned me AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value' . Do you know why this happened?

Comment: my guess is you used `value` instead of `values`. is that right?

Comment: Yes you are right, it's my bad. But when I fixed it it returned me AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unique', which still could not work.

Comment: oops, you can do `np.unique( df.name.values)` or just `df.name.unique()`. sorry i mix those up sometimes.